# how to use Jackson to deserialise a JavaBean including a nest class & List

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JavaBean:

```
public Class Account{
    String userName;
    String id;
    List<Detail> details; 

    class Detail{
        String num;
        String name;
    }
}
```

There's JSON:
`{"username":"Tony","id":"123","details":[{"num":"1","name":"Tom"},{"num":"2","name":"Jerry"}]}`

How can I use Jackson to deserialise ? Thanks

Comment: I don't see a map in the bean.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `userName` field name should be the same as in the json String (username).

Fix the typo in `List<Destail>` to `List<Detail>` and `detail` class name to `Detail`.

Add getters and setters for class fields.

Use the following example to deserialize your json:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"userName\":\"Tony\",\"id\":\"123\",\"details\":[{\"num\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Tom\"},{\"num\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Jerry\"}]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    Account account = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Account.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.Account$Detail]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6e2c9341; line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: com.Account["details"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)